# Living on pure glycogen?

Tags: human-biology, food, carbohydrates

I was recently fascinated when I learned about polysaccharides (I am a biology newbie) and was wondering about some of their properties. After doing some googling I was unable to find any information regarding this scenario.
This is purely theoretical, I am not insane enough to actually try this.

- If my only source of carbohydrates was ingestion of pure glycogen,
  could I live healthily? (assuming I obtain all other necessities for
  life)
- Approximately how many grams of glycogen would I need to live for a
  week (assuming I weigh 150 lbs)? Is this even possible to calculate?
- What does pure glycogen taste like?

Comment: See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4802397/ yes if you take glycogen alongwith proteins, fats, etc. you can survive. As for taste, I don't know how it tastes, it should be tasteless but should become sweet after some time due to action of enzymes.

Comment: If you added that as an answer, I would upvote it. It doesn't address question #2, but it is vastly better than the current lack of answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked three questions here, so I'll answer them one by one.

- Yes, you can survive with glycogen as the only source of *carbohydrates*, assuming that you also take other nutrients like proteins, fats, vitamins, etc. also because carbohydrates cannot supplement all of them. See [this](http://www.livescience.com/51976-carbohydrates.html) article:

  > There are three macronutrients: carbohydrates, protein and fats. Macronutrients are essential for proper body functioning, and the body requires large amounts of them. All macronutrients must be obtained through diet; the body cannot produce macronutrients on its own.
- No, there's no way to calculate this. If we were talking about glucose, a definite range could be given. But since glycogen is a polymer with variable amount of glucose molecules linked together (at least I couldn't find an exact number),  its not possible to tell how many glycogen molecules are needed for the daily metabolism in the body.
- Glycogen is an organic, non-polar polymer, insoluble in water just like starch. It does not have a specific taste, but once you eat it, an enzyme called *salivary amylase* will break it into glucose, maltose and limit dextrins, causing it to taste a bit sweet. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-amylase) article:

  > This enzyme acts on starch, glycogen and related polysaccharides and oligosaccharides producing beta-maltose by an inversion.

[image: Glycogen with glycogenin in center]
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycogen)